# MySql Simple consulta con "Where In" no reconoce Index

Tags: mysql

Buenas, Tengo un problema con el Mysql tengo una tabla bien pequeña:

```
CREATE TABLE `Prueba` (
  `idTipoCliente` int(10) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
  `observacion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTipoCliente`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_mysql500_ci;
```

con solo estas pocas filas

```
INSERT INTO `Prueba` VALUES ('1', 'Cliente1', 'datos1');
INSERT INTO `Prueba` VALUES ('2', 'Cliente2', 'datos2');
INSERT INTO `Prueba` VALUES ('3', 'Cliente3', 'datos3');
```

Entonces estoy intentando hacer una simple consulta como esta:

```
Explain SELECT * FROM `Prueba` WHERE `idTipoCliente` in (1,2,3)
```

y obtengo este resultado

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key  key_len   ref  rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      Prueba  ALL     PRIMARY         NULL NULL      NULL 3   Using where
```

Osea no esta reconociendo el KEY(PRIMARY), pero si hago una consulta como esto

```
Explain SELECT * FROM `Prueba` WHERE `idTipoCliente`>=1;
```

O esto

```
Explain SELECT * FROM `Prueba` FORCE Index(PRIMARY) WHERE `idTipoCliente` in (1,2,3);
```

si reconoce el KEY

Mi problema es por que se pierde el Key cuando uso "where in", por que estoy queriendo usar esta tabla en una consulta mas compleja con varias otras tablas e Inner Join, y la solucion que veo es usar FORCE INDEX, pero queria saber si existe otra solucion.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Esto puede ser mas complejo que solo mirar eso. hay que ver si las estadisticas de tu tabla estan bien actualizadas. y capaz por la cantidad de registros y clausulas where decide que es mas rapido hacer un full scan directo.. la verdad puede ser cualquier cosa.. tendrias que probar agregando mas datos.

Comment: En el in estas poniendo el 100% de las filas, entonces parecería ser mas barato hacer un full scan que usar un indice. Proba si pasa lo mismo si le agregás mas elementos a la tabla.

Comment: El problema no creo que sea de un **primary key**, puede que el problema sea en tus **join**s deberias de publicar tu consulta completa

Comment: Todo parece indicar que es un tema del optimizador usando `ENGINE=MyISAM`, con `InnoDB`, el optimizador usa el índice. Aquí un [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYkt4vhRTdyUDtuFRaXXCr/1).

Comment: Una manera de forzar el índice, asumiendo que la columna `idTipoCliente` siempre es mayor que cero (0), es: `... WHERE \`idTipoCliente\` > 0 OR \`idTipoCliente\` IN (1,2,3);`, ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aYkt4vhRTdyUDtuFRaXXCr/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es muy simple: con tres registros el motor de base de datos considera que *no vale la pena* usar el índice de clave primaria.

Observa lo que ocurre en el código de prueba: **[`ver demo aquí`](http://rextester.com/HSZXR63029)**

1. Cuando usamos los datos originales, en efecto, el índice aparece como `NULL`:

#### `Código`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Prueba` (
  `idTipoCliente` INT(10)   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
  `observacion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL
     ,  PRIMARY KEY (`idTipoCliente`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_mysql500_ci;


INSERT INTO `Prueba` VALUES ('1', 'Cliente1', 'datos1');
INSERT INTO `Prueba` VALUES ('2', 'Cliente2', 'datos2');
INSERT INTO `Prueba` VALUES ('3', 'Cliente3', 'datos3');


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `Prueba` WHERE `idTipoCliente` in (1,2,3);
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
id  select_type   table   partitions  type  possible_keys  key  key_len ref    rows filtered      Extra
1   SIMPLE        Prueba  NULL        ALL   PRIMARY        NULL NULL    NULL     3  100 Using where
```

---

2. Ahora vamos a agregar 1,000 filas a la tabla y veamos lo que ocurre.

#### `Código`:

```
-- Creamos otra tabla exactamente igual

CREATE TABLE `PruebaMax` (
  `idTipoCliente` INT(10)   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL,
  `observacion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL
     ,  PRIMARY KEY (`idTipoCliente`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_mysql500_ci;


-- Agregamos 1,000 registros de prueba

CREATE PROCEDURE testInsert()   
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; 
WHILE (i <= 1000) DO
    INSERT INTO `PruebaMax` (idTipoCliente, descripcion, observacion) values (i, '1', '1');
    SET i = i+1;
END WHILE;
END;

CALL testInsert(); 


EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `PruebaMax` WHERE `idTipoCliente` in (1,2,3);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `PruebaMax`;
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
id  select_type table       partitions  type    possible_keys   key      key_len    ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      PruebaMax   NULL        range   PRIMARY         PRIMARY  4          NULL    3       100         Using index condition

COUNT(*)
1000
```

¿Qué te parece? Cuando tu tabla crezca y se haga mayor, entonces el motor empezará efectivamente a usar el índice de clave primaria. ¿A partir de cuántas filas? Esa podría ser una pregunta interesante.